# Linear optimization problem with additional constant cost for non-zero variables

Tags: linear-programming

I have a linear optimization problem with integer variables of the form

minimize $a_1 x_1 + ... + a_n x_n$

under a set of constraints

- Bounds for each variable $a_i \le constant_i$
- Bounds for groups $ a_{j1} + ... + a_{jk} \le constant_j$

Which R package lpSolve solves nicely even though its quite large.

But now I realized I need to add a constant cost term to the cost-function for each $x_i$ which is non zero.

**Question**: Is there a trick to minimize a cost-function with terms of the form
$a_1 x_1 + f(a_1) + ... + a_n x_n + f(a_n)$ where

$f(x)={0.1 \text{ if } x>0\text{, and }0\text{ otherwise}} $

as if it were truely linear?

Comment: No, requires binary variables.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg lpSolve supports binary variables, but I don't see how to use them for this problem, since I cannot multiply an additional binary variable $b_1$ with $a_1$ to get the desired effect.

Comment: Introduce binaries $z_i$, add the constraints $a_i \leq constant_i z_i$, and add $0.1\sum z_i$ to the objective.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg of course! thank you :) please post as answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce binaries $z_i$, add the constraints $a_i \leq constant_i z_i$, and add $0.1\sum z_i$ to the objective.

Comment: Works like a charm :)